# How to check in which position (landscape or portrait) is the iPhone now?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app with a tab bar, and nav controllers in each tab. When user shakes the device, a `UIImageView` appears as a child view in the nav controller. But the `UIImageView` must contain a special image, depending on the device's current orientation.

If I write just

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)
   if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) { 
   //Code
   }
   else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight||interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
   //Code
   }
}
```

The view just goes crazy if user rotated the device before shaking.

**Is there a method to get iPhones current orientation?**

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use the `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` method, as specified [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006902-CH3-SW3).

Comment: Thanks, but which values can the orientation be? From -90 til 90 - portrait and from -180 til -90 and from 90 til 180-landscape?

Comment: See @Shirkrin's answer - it returns a value of type `UIDeviceOrientation`, which is an `enum` of a certain list of values.

Comment: not worked for me as sometimes it returns UIInterfaceOrientetionUnknown

Comment: Don't work always, i finally check the orientation by my window width. If it is equals 320.0 then is portrait, else landscape.

Comment: @MansApps: That seems fragile – what if you're on an iPad, or what if the next iPhone revision widens the screen past 320 points? The UIDevice class is telling you all it can – if you get an Unknown orientation back, well, then it's really *unknown*. You can pick a default (e.g. default to portrait in that case), but you shouldn't make assumptions that a window width maps to an orientation.

Comment: If you don't care about the *device's* orientation, but rather only the *interface's* orientation, you can ask your current UIViewController for its `-interfaceOrientation` instead. That has no Unknown value, so you'll always get something well-defined back, rather than having to infer an orientation.

Comment: Thank you @Tim, I know that it's not fiable and don't work on iPad. But this is just a momentary solution while i find something better. I will try you second answer ;)!

Comment: Thank you very much @Tim, `-(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation` method declared on `UIViewController` works fine.

Comment: It doesn't tell you if it's `landscape` or `portrait` it tells you more: `landscape`, `portrait` or `flat`

Answer (score 51):

Here are macros `UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape` and `UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait`

so rather checking separately you can do it like this ...

```
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
{
    // code for landscape orientation      
}
```

OR

```
 if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
 {
     // code for Portrait orientation       
 }
```

Comment: I've noticed that these don't return the correct values if the application launches and hasn't changed orientation yet. Is there any way around this?

Comment: swift 4/5? and what about if phone in flat position - how to find out if it's in landscape or portrait?

Answer (score 17):

As beno said, this seems a better answer if you are detecting orientation early in your View. I couldn't get the approved answer to return a result early in my setup but this works wonderfully.

```
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)){
//DO Portrait
}else{
//DO Landscape
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer I needed. For clarification, the `self` in your code is an instance of UIViewController.

Comment: self.interfaceOrientation has been Deprecated since iOS 8.1

Comment: This answer is problematic. `self.interfaceOrientation` is deprecated and it returns a different type than UIDeviceOrientation.

Answer (score 11):

To addon to the already answered question:

You use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` which will yield one of these values:

```
typedef enum {
   UIDeviceOrientationUnknown,
   UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
   UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
   UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft,
   UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
   UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp,
   UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown
} UIDeviceOrientation;
```

The documentation can be found [here - (orientation)](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006902-CH3-SW3) and [here - (UIDeviceOrientation)](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIDeviceOrientation).

(I don't mean to claim the former anwser, but this information was to big for a comment.)

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]
```

Or in Swift 3:

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation
```

To specifically check for a particular orientation you can also try the `isLandscape` or `isPortrait` property like so:

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isLandscape
```

The problem with `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` is that it will also return `UIInterfaceOrientationUnknown` which `statusBarOrientation` does not.

There is also a `UIViewController` property `interfaceOrientation` but it was deprecated in iOS 8, so it's not recommended.

You check documentation for `statusBarOrientation` [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1623026-statusbarorientation)

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the interfaceOrientation property of the UIViewController class, if you are stuck and continuously getting UIDeviceOrientationUnknown from UIDevice.

There's a good summary of why [[UIDevice currentdevice] orientation] can sometimes fail here: http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=25, especially if you want to detect the orientation quickly (for example, if you wanted to check right when the app comes out of the background).

Comment: I think that blog post is the best, and most complete, answer to this question. Thanks for linking to it.

Answer (score 6):

It helps you...

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation ]== UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
 {
   NSLog(@"Lanscapse");
 }
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown )
 {
   NSLog(@"UIDeviceOrientationPortrait");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

- As Simple Solution of Swift 4.2

  ```
  override func didRotate(from fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
          switch UIDevice.current.orientation{
          case .portrait:
              print("Portrait")
          case .portraitUpsideDown:
              print("PortraitUpsideDown")
          case .landscapeLeft:
              print("LandscapeLeft")
          case .landscapeRight:
              print("LandscapeRight")
          default:
              print("Another")
          }
      }
  ```

Answer (score 3):

You can also define constants to earn time :

```
#define LANDSCAPE UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)
#define LANDSCAPE_RIGHT [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft
#define LANDSCAPE_LEFT [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight
#define PORTRAIT UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)
#define PORTRAIT_REVERSE [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown
```

Comment: #define LANDSCAPE UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)

Might want to rework for deprecated methods.

Comment: Should be #define IS_LANDSCAPE UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])

Answer (score 3):

Updating this to iOS 8+ where the `UIViewController.interfaceOrienation` is deprecated, you should use `traitCollections`. So for example, to check for landscape on iPhone, you'd use:

```
if self.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == .compact
{
  your code
}
```

Notice that this is not the case on iPad, because on iPad in landscape, the size class is not `compact`.
[Apple Doc Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitcollection)

[image: Sizes from Apple]

Comment: ⚠️ Watch out, compact / regular has nothing to do with portrait / landscape. Size classes vary depending on device and orientation. See: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout#device-size-classes

Answer (score 2):

And if you simply want whether the device is in landscape or portrait, a simple solution is (in Swift):

```
var orientation = "portrait"
if UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width > UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height {
   orientation = "landscape"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check it like so (Swift 3):

```
var isPortrait: Bool {
  let orientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
  switch orientation {
    case .portrait, .portraitUpsideDown:
      return true

    case .faceUp, .faceDown:
      // Check the interface orientation
      let interfaceOrientation = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation
      switch interfaceOrientation{
        case .portrait, .portraitUpsideDown:
          return true
        default:
          return false
      }
   default: // .unknown
     return false // not very satisfying to return false as if we were in landscape :-/
   }
}
```

If you are in a ViewController, you can also do like so (that is what I ended up doing):

```
private var isPortrait: Bool {
    let orientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
    switch orientation {
    case .portrait, .portraitUpsideDown:
        return true
    case .landscapeLeft, .landscapeRight:
        return false
    default: // unknown or faceUp or FaceDown
        return self.view.width < self.view.height
    }
}
```

Although even this should be enough in that case:

```
private var isPortrait: Bool {
     return self.view.width < self.view.height
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

I got this from another SO answer about 4 yrs ago. I still use it to this day. I don't remember which answer otherwise I would link to it.

Anyway you can use the notification `UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // add this to viewDidLoad
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(deviceOrientationDidChange),
                                               name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification,
                                               object: nil)
}

@objc func deviceOrientationDidChange() {
    
    switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
    
    case .landscapeRight:
        print("landscapeRight")
    case .landscapeLeft:
        print("landscapeLeft")
    case .portrait:
        print("portrait")
    case .faceUp:
        print("faceUp")
    case .faceDown:
        print("faceDown")
    case .portraitUpsideDown:
        print("portraitUpsideDown")
    case .unknown:
        print("unknown")
    default:
        print("default")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the current orientation

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        NSLog(@"Landscape left");
        self.lblInfo.text = @"Landscape left";
    } else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        NSLog(@"Landscape right");
        self.lblInfo.text = @"Landscape right";
    } else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        NSLog(@"Portrait");
        self.lblInfo.text = @"Portrait";
    } else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        NSLog(@"Upside down");
        self.lblInfo.text = @"Upside down";
    }
}
```