# View controller frame.height and frame.width are swapped for iOS 8

Tags: ios, view, ios8

I'm updating an app which runs in landscape and I'm testing in the simulator and on an iPhone 5 running iOS 8. The results from my view controller's value for self.view.frame.size.width are the values I've always received for self.view.frame.size.height in iOS 7 and earlier. Many elements now show with the x and y coordinates now flipped accordingly.

I'm looking for an elegant solution which gets the same behavior as before, perhaps this is not possible with iOS 8 in landscape mode?

Comment: In what method are you logging the size?

Comment: yep, man, it is new behaviour of ios 8.

Comment: Was about to ask a similar question.  @nyekimov - can you post a reference link with more info?  (and maybe post as an answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed by the user nyekimov, it's a new behavior of iOS 8.
There was something related in WWDC 2014 Session 214.
Hope this reference helps :)
To solve the problem I just added a verification of iOS 8 and iPad and swapped the width with height.
(I just got this problem on iPad, that's why I made only for it)

Good luck ! :D

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with my application which also runs solely in Landscape mode - 
I simply used an if statement to correct the issue wherever it occurs.

if(self.view.frame.size.height > self.view.frame.size.width)
{
then you are using iOS versions < 8 and the API is still referencing portrait dimensions.
use your existing code.
}
else
{
you are using iOS 8 and you will need to alter your width/height references 
}

If your application switches orientation then you may need to grab the orientation of the device also - see [device orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516491/how-to-check-in-which-position-landscape-or-portrait-os-the-iphone-now)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If we try to access the values of width and height from self.view.frame.size in ***viewWillLayoutSubviews*** instead from viewWillAppear: will give the proper values.

This worked for me :)